# Big datatype in java

Tags: java, overflow

I have been working on an application. It is related to shopping business.
There is a model that has:

```
 private Float count;
 private Long price;
```

I want to know the best java datatype for `count * price` because of huge amount of `price` and `count`.

Another hand the overflow is not occured when`price` * `count` operation.

Comment: If `count` can be in the millions, and an exact answer is needed, then `Float` (or `float`) is the wrong data type.  I'd suggest `long count;` and `double price;`.  The product wiill be implicilty `double` and that will work for amounts up to about a trillion dollars and still retain accurate rounding to the nearest penny.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/5221149)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## JSR 354: Money and Currency API

As a solution you can consider an approach with the JavaMoney.org library [on GitHub](http://javamoney.github.io). This library implements the [*JSR 354: Money and Currency API*](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=354) specification.

The goals of that API:

1. To provide an API for handling and calculating monetary amounts
2. To define classes representing currencies and monetary amounts, as well as monetary rounding
3. To deal with currency exchange rates
4. To deal with formatting and parsing of currencies and monetary amounts

If you don't want use any library of course you should use `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum value of:

- [`Float`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html) is [`Float.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html#MAX_VALUE), (2-2^23)*2^127, something like 3.40282346638528860e+38 or 340,282,346,638,528,860,000,000,000,000,000,000,000.000000.
- `Long` is [`Long.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE), 2^63-1, or 9,223,372,036,854,776,000.

Just what kind of shopping business are you running that does not fit in those types?

## Floating-point

Actually, you do not want `Float` for the simple reason that it is based on [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) technology, and you never use floating-point for money. Never use floating-point for any context where accuracy is important. Floating-point [trades away accuracy for speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) of execution. Usually, your customers will care about money. So you would never use the `float`, `Float`, `double`, or `Double` types in Java for such purposes. This workaround is prone to confusion and mistakes obviously, so it requires careful documentation and coding.

## `BigDecimal`

Where accuracy matters, such as money, use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Not because it can handle large numbers, but **because it is accurate**. Slow, but accurate.

The advice to use `BigDecimal` applies only where you have a fractional amount such as tracking the pennies on a dollar. If you are using only integer numbers, you have no need for `BigDecimal`.

### Integer workaround for fractional amounts

Indeed a workaround for the floating-point problem in languages lacking an alternative like `BigDecimal` is to multiple all fractional amounts until they become integers. For example, if doing bookkeeping to the penny on a dollar (United States), then multiple all amounts by 100 to keep a count of whole pennies as an integer rather than a count of fractional dollars.

## Integers

As for working with integer numbers in Java, you have [multiple simple choices](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

- For numbers 127 and less, use `byte` or [`Byte`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Byte.html), using [8 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit).
- For numbers 32,767 and less, use `short` or `Short`, using [16 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16-bit).
- For numbers 2^31-1 and less (about 2 billion), use `int` or `Integer`, using [32 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit).
- For numbers 2^63-1 and less (about umpteen gazillion), use `long` or `Long`, using [64 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing).
- For even larger numbers, use `BigInteger`.

Generally best to use the smallest integer type that can comfortably fit your current values as well as fit foreseeable future values.

The 32-bit or 64-bit types are your main choices for modern hardware. You needn't worry about the smallest types unless working with massive amounts of these values, or are quite constrained on memory. And using `BigInteger` is overkill for most any business-oriented app. (Science and engineering apps might be a different story.)

---

See also the [Answer by i.merkurev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53928415/642706) on the *JSR 354: Money and Currency API* library.

Answer (score 0):

For huge values there are BigDecimal or BigInteger classes. I will use BigDecimal in your case. You never get overflow with this classes.